# My Haskell program is too lazy

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a function like:

```
type App a = ExceptT AppError (ResourceT IO)

onEvent :: SDL.EventPayload -> App ()
onEvent event = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "EVE!"
  case event of
    SDL.MouseMotionEvent dat -> do
      liftIO $ putStrLn "HELLO"
    SDL.KeyboardEvent kbe  -> liftIO $ putStrLn "WORLD"
    _ -> return ()
```

That is a callback being used in my app.

This function seemingly doesn't fire, Because none of the putStrLn's print to console.

But this function - with the slight modification does print everything to console:

```
onEvent :: SDL.EventPayload -> App ()
onEvent event = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "EVE!"
  case event of
    SDL.MouseMotionEvent dat -> do
      liftIO $ print dat
    SDL.KeyboardEvent kbe  -> liftIO $ print kbe
    _ -> return ()
```

Why does the full evaluation of `SDL.EventPayload` cause the surrounding `putStrLn`'s to work?

How can I make my function callback a bit more reliable?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a buffering issue?  Try `hPutStrLn stderr` instead.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yes it is just a buffering issue! now I feel kind of stupid...

Comment: Bah, no feeling stupid.  It's a fair question.  Glad things are working.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That should probably be an answer. If you don't want to write it up, I'm happy to!

Comment: @jkeuhlen Knock yourself out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216164/thomas-m-dubuisson) pointed out in the comments, this looks like a buffering problem. The `System.IO` package describes standard [buffering behavior](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:12).

You have a couple of options on how to resolve this kind of issue. You can manually set the buffering mode in your program with:

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

at the beginning of your function. This will turn off all buffering (you could also choose `LineBuffering`) and will print immediately to stdout.

You could also flush the buffer after every print:

```
SDL.MouseMotionEvent dat -> do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "HELLO"
  hFlush stdout
```

Or you can try to print directly to the `stderr` handle which has different default buffering rules:

```
SDL.MouseMotionEvent dat -> do
  liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr "HELLO"
```